# Exporting a project for an older version of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, export, version, project

I am running Android Studio version 3.5.1. My students have version 3.4.2, and it's not practical to update their IDE because of security restrictions on the school computers.

When I export a project as a .zip file, they aren't able to open the project in their IDEs.

Is there a way for 
(a) an older version of Android Studio to import a newer project? 
or
(b) a newer version of Android Studio to export a project for an older IDE?

Comment: Just upload a code in git repo and avoid to use the android gradle plugin 3.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Gradle Plugin is not forward compatible. You can downgrade the Android Gradle Plugin to 3.4.2 if you're not using a specific feature in 3.5.1.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
}
```